# Compare list of strings in two different files vb.net

Tags: string, vb.net, list

I have two different .txt files (requested_description.txt and all_description.txt).

In all_description.txt I have a list of strings, something like this:

**all_description.txt**

> John is a policeman
>   Mike is a doctor
>   Barbara is a model
>   etc...

In other file (requested_description.txt) I will search names from the first file (all_description.txt)

**requested_description.txt**

> John
>   Michael
>   Ivan
>   Donald
>   Barbara
>   etc...

I want to find if the strings (names) from requested_description.txt are the same in all_description.txt

Then I want to show results in output, for example:

John > John is a policeman
Barbara > Barbara is a model

For now I have only this sort of code, I want to use sort method, first to sort ascending then use `for each...` so I'm a little stuck here:

```
  Dim i As Integer = 0
  Dim ReadAllDescrpt As String() =File.ReadAllLines("all_description.txt")
  Dim RqstDescription As String()= File.ReadAllLines("rqst_description.txt")       

  Dim allDescrpt As New List(Of String())
  allDescrpt.Sort()
  For Each descrpt In ReadAllDescrpt
     Console.WriteLine(ReadAllDescrpt)
  Next
  Console.WriteLine()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of needing to sort them, you can use `.Contains` to see if they match, and if they do. Match them.

A small example, using your code:

```
  Dim ReadAllDescrpt As String() =File.ReadAllLines("all_description.txt")
  Dim RqstDescription As String()= File.ReadAllLines("rqst_description.txt")       

  Dim allDescrpt As New List(Of String)
  For Each person as string In RqstDescription 
     dim desc as String = ReadAllDescrpt.FirstOrDefault(Function(x)x.Contains(person))
if desc <> "" Then Console.WriteLine(person & " > " & desc)
  Next
```

I haven't tested this, but this is how it should work. This uses LINQ too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example on sort and check the string array line by line.

```
Dim ReadAllDescrpt As String() = File.ReadAllLines("all_description.txt")
Dim RqstDescription As String() = File.ReadAllLines("requested_description.txt")
Array.Sort(RqstDescription)
For i As Integer = 0 To RqstDescription.Length - 1
    For j As Integer = 0 To ReadAllDescrpt.Length - 1
        If ReadAllDescrpt(j).Contains(RqstDescription(i)) Then
            Console.WriteLine(RqstDescription(i) & " > " & ReadAllDescrpt(j))
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler LINQ, use [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/queries/join-clause). Join on the name in rqst_description and first word in all_description. If you ever end up using first and last name, you need to join accordingly.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim descriptions As String() = File.ReadAllLines("all_description.txt")
    Dim names As String() = File.ReadAllLines("rqst_description.txt")

    Dim result = From name In names
                 Join description In descriptions On name Equals _
                    description.Split({" is a "}, StringSplitOptions.None).First()
                 Select String.Format("{0} > {1}", name, description)

    For Each s In result
        Console.WriteLine(s)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

According to your comment, the files have been changed

**all_description.txt**

> John is a policeman
>   
> Mike is a doctor
>   
> Barbara is a model
>   
> Ivan The Terrible is a nice guy

**rqst_description.txt**

> John Smith
>   
> Michael
>   
> Ivan The Terrible
>   
> Donald
>   
> Barbara

**Output**

> Ivan The Terrible > Ivan The Terrible is a nice guy
>   
>  Barbara > Barbara is a model

Note: Contains works too, but I'm afraid of the `etc...`. If using Contains, you may get a false match i.e. `Jon / Jonathan is a janitor` (no offense to janitors, but Jon is not one).

Comment: I tryed to use you solution but it's not working, nothing happend. And you were right, i cant use contains because i will not get 100% match.

Comment: `nothing happend` can you explain a little more?

Comment: Weird. First of all, put a `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of the code so it doesn't just exit. I will update the sample with this. Make sure that the file `all_description.txt` has {John is a policeman, Mike is a doctor, Barbara is a model}, and `rqst_description.txt` has {John, Michael, Ivan, Donald, Barbara} according to your original example. My files look *exactly* like your block quotes. I just rebuilt a small example from scratch again according to my answer and your files, and it works. Including your file contents, I would consider mine a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't know what's happend but now it's working but i have a little problem, what if i have in list of names for example

John Smith 
and in descriptions 

John is a janitor 

He will find 

John Smith > John is a janitor

Comment: Right, well that's kind of a different question, right? Your original text files only had first names. Of course, it's possible, and I will amend my answer.